# Mac OS X and third party e-mail clients

Tags: macos, mac, apple-mail, email-client, postbox

I have tried several third party e-mail clients on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard and up), most notable Sparrow and Postbox.

There seem to be a few applications that do not work with an e-mail client other than the standard Mail.app.

The weirdest example is Preview (Preview.app). When Postbox or Sparrow is set as the default e-mail client, it does not show the option to share a PDF through e-mail (screenshot below is with Dutch language, Voorvertoning == Preview, Bericht == Message):

[image]

Also, MS Word and Excel form Office for Mac have the option to send a document as e-mail attachment greyed out.

When switching back to Mail.app as default e-mail client, all the options mentioned reappear.

Question:

1. Is this a known bug?
2. Is there a way to make these options appear (working) when using Postbox?

Answer (score 1):

Apple hard codes the integrations between Mail.app and other Apple apps.  It's a proprietary interface and they have not exposed an API for developers to utilize.